# Orchard and CSS Preprocessing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, orchardcms

Has anyone attempted to use a CSS Preprocessing when doing Front End Development in Orchard (particularly with Bootstrap)?

I currently use Web Matrix for all my Orchard dev work, but looking to expand beyond the available Bootstrap themes and incorporate LESS. I'm unsure of the best route to go.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: You may want to consider reading into a separate "Front End" development process. Whilst it's nice to keep everything all together in the same environment, I've found it much easier to handle SASS (or LESS, or whichever flavour of preprocessing you're using) builds separately with a tool such as Grunt or Gulp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use WebMatrix, then install this extension, which will compile your LESS files from the IDE when you save them. http://extensions.webmatrix.com/packages/OrangeBits

Comment: I'm slowly moving on to working in VS, but there's a lot to digest in that environment/with the source code. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instructions that reverand put on this site:
http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/291401

Still new to Orchard myself, and this post is pretty old. Basically he says that you need to install a DotLess module that will translate your less file into css.

Comment: Sadly the developer stopped developing it few years ago